# Django check if model has related object before deleting the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

After looking for a way to check if a model instance can be deleted in django, I found many options, but none was working as expected. Hope this solution can help.

Let start by creating an Abstract model class which can be inherited by other model

```
class ModelIsDeletable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def is_deletable(self):
        # get all the related object
        for rel in self._meta.get_fields():
            try:
                # check if there is a relationship with at least one related object
                related = rel.related_model.objects.filter(**{rel.field.name: self})
                if related.exists():
                    # if there is return a Tuple of flag = False the related_model object
                    return False, related
            except AttributeError:  # an attribute error for field occurs when checking for AutoField
                pass  # just pass as we dont need to check for AutoField
        return True, None

     class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

## Example

So let say we have three model  Organization and Department and StaffType
So many Department can be in an Organization
And an Organization has a particular StaffType

```
class StaffType(ModelIsDeletable):
    pensionable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Organization(ModelIsDeletable):
    staff_type = models.ForeignKey(to=StaffType)


class Department(ModelIsDeletable):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(to=Organization, to_field="id")
```

so let say after adding some information you want to remove an organization model instance
that is already tied to a Department

For instance we have
Organization Table => (name = Engineering, pk = 1)
Department Table => (name=Developer, organization_fk=1, pk=1)

Now when you try to delete an organization after get it with the pk

```
a_org = Organization.objects.get(pk=1)
```

With this at hand you can check if it deletable

```
deletable, related_obj = a_org.is_deletable()

if not deletable:
    # do some stuff with the related_obj list

else:
    # call the delete function
    a_org.delete()
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659023/deletion-objects-that-is-used-as-foreign-key

Comment: ...Is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: There is no question there just answer to  the particular problem

Comment: This is from https://gist.github.com/freewayz/69d1b8bcb3c225bea57bd70ee1e765f8

Comment: That is my snippet from my github account.

Answer (score 3):

Your question appears to be "How to detect what related model objects would be deleted if I delete this model object?" or "How to detect what related rows would be deleted if I delete this row?"

Another option is to use a transaction, do the delete, save the information provided by django, but rollback before committing the change. This works in databases like Postgres and MySQL, but I don't know about others.

In this example I want to know what will be deleted if I delete my organization named 'pdemo', and I see that it has 408 related Property objects.

https://gist.github.com/cgthayer/25aa97bb4b74efb75e3467fb7bbdaacb

```
>>> from django.db import transaction
>>> transaction.set_autocommit(autocommit=False)
>>> o = Organization_v2.objects.get(name='pdemo')
>>> del_info = o.delete()
>>> del_info
(1404, {'data.Property': 408, [..more stuff..], 'data.Organization_v2': 1})
>>> Property.objects.filter(scope__organization_id=o).count()
0
>>> transaction.rollback()
>>> o = Organization_v2.objects.get(name='pdemo')
>>> Property.objects.filter(scope__organization_id=o).count()
408
```

This could be translated into a generic function.

When looking into this, I found many old solutions that use the functions in the django.contrib.admin to determine this, but that's an undocumented api that seems to change from time to time, so using transactions seems to be easier *iff* your database supports it.