# make /one/{id}/two in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## models.py

```
class One(models.Model):
    hav = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nat = models.CharField(max_length=34)

class Two(models.Model):
    seti = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    raj = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    one = models.ForeignKey(One)
```

## serializers.py

```
class OneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = One
        fields = '__all__'
class TwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Two
            fields = '__all__'
```

## views.py

```
class OneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
    queryset = One.objects.all()

  class TwoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TwoSerializer
    queryset = Two.objects.all()
```

I have two seperate views for One and Two. So, I need to give 2 urls ie. `/one/` and `/two/.` How can I make single or many views(if necessary) to make two work on single url like `/one/{id}/two/`. What are the possible ideas? Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

you need nested viewsets which is provided in [this](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes) package.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here (as it looks pretty similar with what you need to do):

[how to: creating a view and serializer for adding, editing, and deleting objects with foreign relationships django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078782/how-to-creating-a-view-and-serializer-for-adding-editing-and-deleting-objects/49081736#49081736)